# Webcam LED remains ON after component is unmounted ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, camera, mediastream

My React application keeps ON the webcam after the component is unmounted. Using navigator, MediaRecorder. I tried to set null for the webcamRef, videoRef and setting the mediaStream null when the componentWillUnmount. Nothing is working. The camera LED is ON even after the component is unmounted. Using a forwardRef to create this component.

And also is there any way to get the recorded blob after stopping the recording in synchronous way. Currently I used a promise with a timeout

If anyone have a correct implementation of camera handling please share the repo link with me.
Thanks in advance.

```
 const handleStopMedia = async () => {
   setCameraIsOn(false);
   setRecordingIsOn(false);
   if (mediaStream) {
     const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
     mediaRecorder.stop();
     mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
   }
   setMediaStream(null);
   return await new Promise((resolve) =>
     setTimeout(() => resolve(recordingBlob?.current), 2000)
   );
 };
 
 const handleStartRecording = async () => {
  startTimer();
  setRecordingIsOn(true);
  setRecordingStatus("RECORDING");
   if (mediaStream) {
     const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
     const chunks: BlobPart[] = [];
  
     mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
       if (event.data.size > 0) {
         chunks.push(event.data);
       }
     };
   
     mediaRecorder.start();
     
     // To stop the recording based on the time limit
     {
       props.recordingDuration &&
         setTimeout(() => {
           handleStopRecording();
         }, props.recordingDuration);
     }
     
     const onStopPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
       mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
         const recordedBlob = new Blob(chunks, {
           type: "video/mp4",
         });
         console.log("RecordedBlob:", recordedBlob);
         recordingBlob.current = recordedBlob;
         
         const recordedUrl = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
         videoRef.current.src = recordedUrl;
         setRecordingStatus("STOPPED");
         resolve(recordedBlob);
       };
     });
     
     const recordedBlob = await onStopPromise;
     props.onRecordingStopped &&
       (await props.onRecordingStopped(recordedBlob as Blob));
   }
 };
 
// <video
//    className="webcam-video-view w-full h-full object-cover "
//    ref={webCamRef}
//    autoPlay
//    muted
//    playsInline
// />
```